# Display error font when exporting Excel file

Tags: java, excel, export

I am coding a Java Swing application for writing data to Excel file. Data is Japanese text.
I code on MacOS, it displays so well but then I bring the execute file (.jar) to Windows, I have problems with the font.
Here is my code:

```
public static void writeStudentsListToExcel(ArrayList<MyContent> contentList) {

    Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

    Sheet studentsSheet = workbook.createSheet("MySheet");
    HSSFFont hSSFFont = (HSSFFont) workbook.createFont();
    hSSFFont.setFontName(HSSFFont.FONT_ARIAL);
    HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = (HSSFCellStyle) workbook.createCellStyle();
    cellStyle.setFont(hSSFFont);

    int rowIndex = 0;
    for (MyContent ct : contentList) {
        Row row = studentsSheet.createRow(rowIndex++);
        int cellIndex = 0;

        HSSFCell cell1 = (HSSFCell) row.createCell(cellIndex++);
        cell1.setCellValue(ct.getStt());
        cell1.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

        HSSFCell cell2 = (HSSFCell) row.createCell(cellIndex++);
        cell2.setCellValue(ct.getContents());
        cell2.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

        HSSFCell cell3 = (HSSFCell) row.createCell(cellIndex++);
        cell3.setCellValue(ct.getContentsTrim());
        cell3.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
    }

    // write this workbook in excel file.
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(FILE_OUTPUT);
        workbook.write(fos);
        fos.close();

        System.out.println(FILE_OUTPUT + " is successfully written");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is your problem exactly? How do your fonts actually look and how do you want them to look? More input needed.

Comment: For example, When running on MacOS, it displays "鄢 ぎゅ秵ꤎ䣥禌 榯姎め". When I build then run execute file on Windows, it does not display like that.

Comment: Which version of Apache POI are you currently using?

Answer (score 0):

The following should be sufficient to print Japanese characters and works fine for me:

```
HSSFFont hSSFFont = (HSSFFont) workbook.createFont();
hSSFFont.setFontName(HSSFFont.FONT_ARIAL);
hSSFFont.setCharSet(HSSFFont.ANSI_CHARSET);
```

This is probably an encoding issue, if you are having problems with your code. Make sure you use the latest version of the POI library, which currently is [Apache POI 3.13](https://poi.apache.org/download.html). Also, make sure your text is encoded correctly within your application.